# Доступ к map по ключу через el-выражения

Tags: java, веб-программирование, java-ee, jsp, jstl

Добрый день!

У меня в бине есть мап, из которого надо вывести определенные значения по ключу на jsp-страницу.

```
<jsp:useBean id="user" class="bean.UserLoginBean" scope="session"/>
<p><font size=2 color=red><c:out value="${errors['login']}"/></font></p>
```

В данном случае ключ - login.

Мой мап:

```
Map<String, String> errors = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

Собственно сам вопрос, как вывести значение из мапы по ключу на jsp-страницу, используя jstl?

Comment: `ключ - login` - Ключ в переменной login, или ключ - строка "login"?

Comment: ключ - строка логин

Answer (score 1):

Похоже на то, что вы ошибочно использовали одиночные кавычки вместо парных.

```
<p><font size=2 color=red><c:out value="${errors["login"]}"/></font></p>
```

Comment: если использовать парные кавычки, то пишет multiple annotations и вылетает JasperException